HubSpot OAuth tokens not received when user is not logged in, but works fine when already logged in
I am integrating HubSpot OAuth into my application. When the user is already logged in to HubSpot, the OAuth flow works perfectly, and I receive the tokens without any issues. However, when the user is not logged in to HubSpot and logs in during the OAuth flow, I do not receive the tokens as expected.
Here's the code:
const tokenResponse = await axios.post('https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token', params.toString(), {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
});

const tokens = { ...tokenResponse.data, code };
console.log('Received tokens:', tokens);

return response.status(200).send(
  `<html>
    <head><title>HubSpot Integration</title></head>
    <body>
      <h2>HubSpot App Installed Successfully!</h2>
      <p>You can close this window now.</p>
      <button onclick="window.close()">Close</button>
      <script>
        console.log(window.opener);
        if (window.opener) {
          window.opener.postMessage(${JSON.stringify(tokens)}, "http://localhost:3000/integrations");
        }
        console.log(window.location);
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>`
);


The issue occurs only when the user needs to log in to HubSpot before completing the OAuth flow. The flow redirects the user to HubSpot for authentication in a new window, but after logging in, I do not receive the tokens in my app. When the user is already logged in, everything works fine.

Checking the logs to see if the request to exchange the code for tokens is being made (it is).
Confirming that the same request works when the user is already authenticated.
Double-checked the HubSpot OAuth documentation and made sure the redirect URL and app scopes are correctly set.
Though I am able to receive the tokens, but the communication does not take place between the client and server


Share what you received instead of tokens? What actually happens?

What did the console.log(window.opener) result in?

@Evert I did receive the tokens but through postMessage method I am not receiving the tokens probably because the parent URL is getting lost since there are multiple domains coming in during login

@C3roe Its results in the backend URL localhost:2000 and the details about it

"but the communication does not take place between the client and server" - you are referring to the window.opener.postMessage call here, or something else? Does the browser console have anything relevant to say?

yes I referred to window.opener.postMessage call here, because during login in hubspot the domains change due to which the parent reference is lost and communication does not happen. But when the user is already logged in hubspot then everything works fine
